# Fix active Nav Link in React Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

[image]

Whenever I click a Nav Link, it does not set the link to active. Shouldn't Bootstrap be doing this automatically? I've seen some suggestions on adding css code, but how would I manually add CSS code to a link. Ex: User clicks "Search Youtube" then I apply a CSS to that link? Thank you.

```
<Navbar bg="dark navbar-dark" fixed="top" >
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        <Nav.Link onClick={this.searchYoutubePage} >Search Youtube</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link onClick={this.urlPage} >URL</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link onClick={this.uploadFilePage}>Upload File</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
                <button class="borderlessButton" onClick={this.closeModal}><BsXCircle /></button>
            </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `active` to work you need to set the `active` prop on your link when you want it to showup as active:

```
// activeCondition should be true whenever you want
// e.g. maybe you can make it true inside searchYoutubePage
<Nav.Link active={activeCondition} onClick={this.searchYoutubePage}>
  Search Youtube
</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: Okay. Will add an active condition that sets one link to true and others to false. Thanks!